# Rails - Call Ajax only after visual effect has completed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I would like to make an ajax call only after my FadeOut effect has finished.
That's my simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeIt(id) {
    $(id).slideUp();        
}
</script>

<%= link_to_remote('Delete', :url => {:action => "ajaxdestroy", :controller => "blog_comments", :blog_post_id => @blog_post.id, :id => comment.id}, :before => "closeIt('comment#{comment.id}')", :update => "blogPostComments", :confirm => 'Are you sure?') %></p>
```

Right now the generated html looks like that:

```
<a onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { closeIt('comment39'); new Ajax.Updater('blogPostComments', '/blog_comments/ajaxdestroy/39?blog_post_id=6', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('Xzvq2/0BlbVi3eVCxW5TGcKmap3nrVC1SiG76W+bVGc=')}); }; return false;" href="#">Delete</a>
```

So the effect closeIt function is called but the ajax call finishes before the slideUp effect. How can I call the Ajax function in callback of previous closeIt function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<a onclick="return closeThat(39);" href="#">Delete</a>



function closeThat(id) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        closeIt('comment'+id, function() {
            new Ajax.Updater('blogPostComments', '/blog_comments/ajaxdestroy/'+id+'?blog_post_id=6', {
                asynchronous: true,
                evalScripts: true,
                parameters: 'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('Xzvq2/0BlbVi3eVCxW5TGcKmap3nrVC1SiG76W+bVGc=')
            });
        });
    }
    return false;
}


function closeIt(id, callback) {
    $(id).slideUp(400, callback);        
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christophe but how can I make this javascript code be generated from the rails code? In fact the javascript code is generated automatically

Comment: <%= link_to_remote('Delete', :url => {:action => "ajaxdestroy", :controller => "blog_comments", :blog_post_id => @blog_post.id, :id => comment.id}, :before => "closeIt('comment#{comment.id}')", :update => "blogPostComments", :confirm => 'Are you sure?') %>          generates the javascript code. I can use :before symbol to define a javascript function that is called before the Ajax call but I don't know how to make the Ajax call be called as callback of the :before function

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved using javascript after the has been created. I removed the :before and :confirm symbols from link_to_remote and added an 'id' field to the generated  element

```
 <%= link_to_remote 'Cancella', {:url => {:action => "ajaxdestroy", 
                                          :controller => "blog_comments", 
                                          :blog_post_id => @blog_post.id, 
                                          :id => comment.id},
                                 :update => "blogPostComments"},
                                 {:id => "delete#{comment.id}"} %></p>

     <script>   
         var onClick<%=comment.id%> = new Function($('#delete<%= comment.id%>').attr('onClick'));  //get the ajax call autogenerated        
         function nuova() {   //define a new function to wrap it
              if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { //move here the confirm message
                  $('#comment<%= comment.id%>').hide(600,onClick<%=comment.id%>);
              }
              return false;     
    }                                   
         $('#delete<%= comment.id%>').removeAttr('onclick').click(nuova);
    </script>
```

Not the cleanest but that's a solution. Now the Delete ajax call is submitted only after the effect has terminated